# bootstrap: create searchable multiselect dropdown like Semantic UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, semantic-ui

I have not found any solution yet to the following situation:

[image: searchbar multiselect]

I have built my website on bootstrap. Now the framework is great and useful, only I am missing a neat searchbar with multiselect options.

the above picture shows the one I have right now. It is an input group with appended buttons.
What I found is that Semantic UI is having a nice multiselect dropdown component.

you can see the example here under "Multiple Search Selection": https://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html

Adding this straight to my code is easy, but whats not (at least for me) is to create a searchbar like the one in the picture above.

an input with appended buttons (one for further options and a search button).

What I want to achieve is to search through my database (with Ajax and which works fine for now) and displaying multiselections in my input/select field.

[image: multiselect semantic ui]

It should then look like this above.
Now there is an input group version in Semantic UI (https://semantic-ui.com/elements/input.html) but this is not multi selection like my searchbar at the top.

How can I create a multiselect semantic UI version of my bootstrap searchbar without switching the whole website to semantic ui?
it should behave like the multiselect dropdown from semantic ui (like displaying formatted HTML results in the dropdown from which I can choose from) and post via AJAX a unique url (with the option of the "globe" menu next to the search button).

I would appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you aren't depended on a specific plugin, you can use select2:

https://select2.org/selections -> search for multi-value or multiple 
https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax -> when you have to use ajax

**Edited**: you can use *select2-bootstrap-theme* 
https://select2.github.io/select2-bootstrap-theme/4.0.3.html

Comment: thank you. I managed to display select2 with bootstrap4 "addon" css. looks fine.
just dont get the ajax response to work..

Comment: Have you tried to implement code from the second link? If it has helped you please try to upvote my answer. Thanks

Comment: I implemented before you commented :D
but ok.